# Is there a has_association?('association_name') method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I only want to remove resources if they actually belong to the object. For example:

```
Post.all.each do |post|
    if post.has_method?('name')
        true
    else
        false
    end
end
```

But checking for an association:

```
Post.all.each do |post|
    if post.has_many?('tags')
        true
    else
        false
    end
end
```

or:

```
Post.all.each do |post|
    if post.belongs_to?('category')
        true
    else
        false
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write your own methods:

```
def has_many?(association)
  self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).any?{|a| a.name == association}
end

def belongs_to?(association)
  self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).any?{|a| a.name == association}
end
```

so

```
Post.all.each do |post|
  post.has_many?('tags') ? "yeap" : "nope"
  post.belongs_to?('category') ? "yeap" : "nope"
end
```

Or you can use simple construction:

```
Post.all.each do |post|
  post.methods.include?('tags') ? true :false
  post.methods.include?('category') ? true :false
  post.methods.include?('name') ? true :false
end
```

**UPD**

Or, as you correctly pointed, you can use `respond_to?`

```
 post.respond_to? :comments
```

Comment: yo, what about this `.respond_to?(:tag)`

Comment: @Codeglot, `respond_to?` will fit your needs perfect as well. It is pretty the same as `methods.include?` but shorter

Answer (score 1):

Since Rails >= 6.1, ActiveRecord has been providing two related methods.

The one the OP is looking for is `#associated` and can be used like this:

```rb
Post.where.associated(:tags)
```

The inverse of that is `#missing`.

```rb
Post.where.missing(:tags)
```

...which returns Post models without any tags.

[The API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html) have the details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like (in Rails 3)?:

```
if Post.categories.exists?   # Rails 2 syntax would be Post.categories.present? (I think)
  true
else
  false
end
```

Comment: `Post.categories.exists?` will throw an error if there is no any `categories` method

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm actually on a rails 2.x app :(